# Dense set in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $M=\{2^a 3^b: a,b \in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense $[0,\infty)$

Therefore I want to show that $\overline{M}=[0,\infty)$

$\overline{M}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ because $M\subseteq[0,\infty)$

For the other direction I have an element $x\in[0,\infty)$, now I need to show that $\exists (x_n)\in\overline{M}:x_n\rightarrow x$, i.e to show $\exists (a_n)(b_n)\in\mathbb Z:x_n=2^{a_n}3^{b_n}\rightarrow x$.

Could you help me with that direction?

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, of course there are different ways proving this result, but I would like to be most interested in the continuation of my approach. If you know different solution approaches it is also interesting to know them and discuss them.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you only need to prove that your set is dense in $\Bbb Q_+$ since $\Bbb Q_+$ is dense in $\Bbb R_+$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general if $x,y\in\mathbb N, \ y>1$ and there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid x$ and $p\nmid y$ then the set $M=\{x^a y^b: a,b \in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$.

Proof:
[Kronecker's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html) can be stated as:
 If $\xi$ is irrational then the set $\{n\xi+m:n,m\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Now use the fact that $\frac{\ln x}{\ln y}$ is irrational.

Comment: I know what you mean, I can also consider $A=\{n\log2+m\log3: m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and this is by Kronecker dense in $\mathbb R$ and because of $e^A$ the set $M$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$ but I want to do it in a different way.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a different way? Is this a homework?

Comment: No it is not a homework, I want to try it for myseld in a different way because I think the sequence approach is more general than using Kronecker.

Comment: It is inherently a Diophantine approximation problem.  Doubt one can avoid the ideas.

Comment: If you "want(ed) to do it in a different way", why not mention the fact in the question? (Irrespectively of whether, in the present case, there is or there is not "a different way".)

Comment: "The sequence approach is more general"? Note that $x_{m,n}:=2^m3^n$ over $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is the set of values of a sequence as $\mathbb{Z}^2\simeq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @julien Could you explain this a little bit more in detail?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x>0$ and let $\varepsilon>0$.  As in P.'s proof, which looks fine to me, we can choose $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ so that

$$x< 2^a 3^b <x+\varepsilon.$$

To see this, simply take the logarithm and divide through by $\log(3)$ to show that your inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{\log(x)}{\log(3)} < a\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}+b < \frac{\log(x+\varepsilon)}{\log(3)}.$$

Again, as in P.'s answer, the existence of $a$ and $b$ follows from Kronecker's theorem.

Finally, if you really want to construct a sequence of such numbers that converges to $x$, simply choose $a_n$ and $b_n$ so that

$$x< 2^{a_n} 3^{b_n} <x+\frac{1}{n}.$$

Then the sequence defined by $x_n = 2^{a_n} 3^{b_n}$ satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, how would you choose $a_n,b_n$ explicitly? Or is it enough to conlcude the proof using the log argument?

Comment: @Alexander I think that P.'s proof (or the log argument, as you call it), is clearly sufficient. The point I'm trying to make is that the existence of your desired sequence follows easily from the inequality here.